# Char gets garbage value when reading data in loop

Tags: c++, stdin, getline

I have a problem with reading data in loop. Although the code seems to me to be good, for some test cases it breaks down. Here is simplified program code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string str1, str2, str3;
    char choice;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> choice;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, str1);
        if (choice == 'a') {
            getline(cin, str2);
            getline(cin, str3);
            // ...
            // operations not related to data input
            // ...
        } else if (choice == 'b') {
            getline(cin, str2);
            // ...
            // operations not related to data input
            // ...
        } else if (choice == 'c') {
            // ...
            // operations not related to data input
            // ...
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input value of choice is always 'a', 'b' or 'c', but during the program it sometimes gets other value.
I tried to use scanf instead, but it didn't change the result.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: On a side note, this looks like a great candidate for a ```switch``` statement

Comment: I ran this and all seems to be good. Value of choice is always showing what I had entered.